# get selected values of Picklist (Multi-Select) as list of string

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, multi-select

I'm trying to get selected values and labels of picklist (Multi-Select) for a record of custom object and store these values in list of string but size of it not displayed.

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class customCtrl {
    private ApexPages.standardController stdController;

    Id recordId = 'a0Z25000001Vq02';
    public String[] tmpString { set {
        customObj__c a = [SELECT list_tasks__c
                          FROM customObj__c
                          WHERE Id =: recordId limit 1];
        this.tmpString = a.list_tasks__c.split(';');
    } get;}


    public customCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.stdController = stdController;
    }
}
```

VisualForce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="customObj__c" extensions="customCtrl" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="List of Selected">
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
          list length is {!tmpString.size}

      </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried this and it is the same, return nothing @Ratan

Comment: `list_tasks__c` field having values?

Comment: You should define default constructor in the class as **public customCtrl() {}** then try.

Comment: of course, list of values and I created record and I select values from this list (2 of 8) .. and the record id is a0Z25000001Vq02

Comment: I already do that ` public customCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { this.stdController = stdController;}` @PeeyushSachdeva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller code and add code into constructor

```
public with sharing class customCtrl {


    private ApexPages.standardController stdController;

    public List<String> tmpString {get; private set}

    public customCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.stdController = stdController;
            Id recordId = 'a0Z25000001Vq02';
            tmpString = new List<String>();
            customObj__c a = [SELECT list_tasks__c
                          FROM customObj__c
                          WHERE Id =: recordId limit 1];
            tmpString.addAll(a.list_tasks__c.split(';'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Humm, it works for me thank you. but what is the point ?? what if I want to get these values for each selected record from table for example.

Comment: @user3003810 what do you mean I didn't get you

Comment: I mean this code will be triggered on first page load, what If I'd a table of records and when I click on any row I'll get selected list of tasks for that record? as a method getSelected(Id)

Comment: @user3003810 you may need to pass you row record id in controller and based id need to query to get list